# phalcon phql find query with array element in where

Tags: php, find, phalcon

i am using phalcon's find query, 
and using an array element in the where clause, but getting an error

"'Scanning error before '3] > :from_time:...' when parsing: SELECT..."

i have a work around, not using phalcon's find, but want to figure this out, how to use an array element in where clause, any idea would be welcome.
Thanks, Tal

phalcon (version 3.4.1)

PostgreSQL 9.6.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
class Products extends Model
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSource("products");
    }

    public function findByIdAndTime($id, $from_time)
    {
        $result = Products::find(["id=:id: AND create_time[3] > :from_time:",
        ['id' => $Id,'from_time' => $from_time]]);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

use example:

```
try
{
    $products = new Products();
    $products->findByIdAndTime(1, 1541672000);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

the postgre DB table column create_time is of type integer[] (in example {1541600807,0,1541673916}), and the value of $from_time is a previously inserted now_time() from the DB (1541672000 in example)

here is how to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE public.products
(
    id int,
    create_time int[]
);

INSERT INTO products(create_time) VALUES ('{1541600807,0,1541673916}');
```

Comment: Where does `$Id` come from? Where does `$from_time` come from? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without more infomation, it will be really hard to help you.

Comment: What is `create_time[3]`? This has to be your db column... What is the value of `$from_time`

Comment: nikolay-mihaylov, the create_time column is of type integer[] (in example {1541600807,0,1541673916}), so i refer to the 3rd element in the array, and the value of $from_time is a previously inserted now_time() from the DB (1541675158 in example)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function findByIdAndTime($id, $from_time)
{
    $result = Products::find([
        'conditions' => 'id= :id: AND create_time[3] > :from_time:',
        'bind' => [
            'id' => $id,
            'from_time' => $from_time
        ]
    ]);

    return $result;  
}
```

Comment: same error "'Scanning error before '3] > :from_time:...' when parsing: SELECT...", but nice idea, thanks.